# SpringBoot - SpringFox Starter 3.0.0 - Unable to detect WebFlux RouterFunction

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux, springfox-boot-starter

I am using SpringBoot WebFlux Springfox-starter for the project.

The issue is this not detecting the RouterFunction methods. The above methods are detecting without any issues but it is not working for RouterFunctions.

```
@Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(GreetingHandler greetingHandler) {
    return RouterFunctions
        .route(RequestPredicates.GET("/hello")
                .and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)),
            greetingHandler::hello);
  }

  @Component
  public static class GreetingHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> hello(ServerRequest request) {
      return ServerResponse.ok()
          .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
          .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("Hello, SpringFox!"));
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/springfox/springfox

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have hosted the entire project in the below location. Please let me know if anyone experience the same or additional configuration missing here.

https://github.com/chamithchathuka/demowebflux-2

[image]https://github.com/chamithchathuka/demowebflux-2/tree/master

Comment: Have you even checked before asking here if springfox has support for RouterFunctions (my guess is it doesn’t)

Comment: There is another version that supports reactive endpoints  https://springdoc.org/

Comment: @AleGallagher I have tried with spring docs for functional programming it is working with some modifications for the codes. I will wait and post the answer here.